Vuetify steppers + Vuelidate nested components dynamic scope
Trying to setup form validation for Vuetify steppers with Vuelidate.
I'm making use of nested components with each component it's own validation.
<template>
  <VStepper v-model="page" alt-labels :elevation="0">
    <VStepperHeader>
      <VStepperItem
        value="loans"
        title="Leningen"
        icon="mdi-percent"
      ></VStepperItem>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <VStepperItem
        value="income"
        title="Inkomen"
        icon="mdi-currency-eur"
      >
      </VStepperItem>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <VStepperItem
        value="summary"
        title="Overzicht"
        icon="mdi-file-chart"
      ></VStepperItem>
    </VStepperHeader>
    <VStepperWindow>
      <LoanStep />
      <IncomeStep />
      <SummaryStep />
    </VStepperWindow>
    <template #actions="{ next, prev }">
      <VStepperActions @click:next="handleNextStep(next)" @click:prev="prev" />
    </template>
  </VStepper>
</template>
<script setup>
const page = ref('loans')
const v$ = useVuelidate({}, {}, { $scope: page.value })

const handleNextStep = async (next) => {
  if (!await v$.value.$validate()) return false

  next()
}

</script>

Notice the scope I am setting in the useVuelidate function, it equals 'loans' on startup.
A loan component looks like this:
const v$ = useVuelidate({
  title: {
    required
  },
  investment: {
    required
  },
  period: {
    required
  },
  apr: {
    required
  }
}, loan, {
  $scope: 'loans'
})

This works, but when I go to the next step the page changes to 'income'. The income component looks like this:
const v$ = useVuelidate({
  person1: {
    required,
    minValue: minValue(1)
  },
}, income, { $scope: 'income' })

But here the validations of income are not taken into account when clicking 'next'.
I tried passing along the page as a ref in the parent component, but that doesn't seem to be working. The problem probably is $scope is not reactive. There isn't a global setter for $scope that I am aware of.
